# Xcode Debugger does not work on first app installation

Tags: xcode, debugging

Every time I install a fresh copy of my app on my testing device the debugger is not showing any output. Rebuilding the project solves it.

What could be the problem, or any suggestions how to explore this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain you down votes ?

Comment: Forgive me for asking the obvious, but are you running to your device as opposed to archiving and installing via itunes?

Comment: I am running on device, We are a team and the problem replicate on all of the computers and devices.

Comment: Are you getting any build errors or warnings in the Log Navigator? Especially with the ProcessProductPackaging CodeSign. Do you have any custom Build Phases?

Comment: @GayleDDS The log navigator is empty

Comment: @GayleDDS We have custom builds but the problem is happening even when we remove them.

Comment: @shannoga the log navigator is totally empty, is it the Debug Entry? How about the Build entry before the Debug?

Comment: @shannoga also check the console for the device. In the Organizer, Device Tab, Find your active device and select Console.

Comment: @GayleDDS  I will check the device entry, as for the Build entry, I don't see that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After eliminating many options we found that the cause is the `voip` (Voice Over IP) flag in the `UIBackgroundModes` inside the `info.plist` causes this problem.

We have reported Apple about this.

Thanks for any help suggested.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing.  We also have Voice over IP. Did you figure it out?  Did you find a way to print to console on first app installation with Voice over IP background mode enabled?

Comment: Did not find any solution

Comment: I noticed that if I install the app from Testflight i get a voip token A from the didUpdatePushCredentials method in Appdelegate.  If I then build from Xcode (replacing the Tesflight install) I get the same token A the first time, however, the second time I build the app, I get a new token B.  Not sure if it has anything to do with it ?

Comment: Hi, any updates on this, I have had the same problem for months?

Answer (score 0):

Start by deleting the app from your device and then cleaning your derived data. Do a clean build (Command + Shift + K) and see if that helps.

You should also check your project scheme, by clicking on the scheme, Edit Scheme.... Then check for the debugger settings there.

To run your app, plug in your device, and hit Command  + R. The debugger should appear in the bottom corner. If not, hit Command + Shift + Y (in Xcode 4) to bring up the console and debug panels.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have 3 ways to resolve that:

Check if The phone's name contain's an apostrophe if it has remove it and try again.

Disconnect your device from the MAC. Remove your development provisioning profile from your device, power down the device, wait a minute, power on, reconnect to MAC, and let XCode reinstall profile.

Before do this second way, if you have another device try it, to have sure if it's not from xcode, if it's not the device, try to reinstall xcode, if it's the device, return the device to default factory settings and try it.

Comment: Tried all that, no help. Thanks